# Cannot get Kubota tractor engine to fire

Tags: starting, ignition, small-engine, tractor

I have a Kubota T2080 lawn tractor. It has a basic 2-cylinder gasoline naturally aspirated engine. I let it sit last winter and now that it's the spring, I cannot get the engine to fire. The electric starter spins forever and sounds normal but the engine doesn't seem to be firing.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Checked choke cable: seems fine and engages correctly
- Charging the battery overnight: no change
- Oil+filter was changed: no change too
- Fuel filter was also changed (old one wasn't in the best condition)
- The engine is definitely sucking in fuel
- Air filter was cleaned
- Taking the spark plugs out and visually looking for ignition: there is no spark on both cylinders
- Regap the spark plugs to 0.03": no change, gap was around 0.05"
- While they were out, air comes out from the holes during the starter cranking

Is it possible that the ignition coil just somehow went bad over one winter? What else should I be checking?

Edit: I actually think it might be getting a spark but I either couldn't see it in the sunlight or I wasn't grounding it correctly. I'll confirm it later today.

Edit 2: I'm thinking it's probably the carb. I forgot to put stabil in it last year and I never shut the petcock

Edit 3: Well, I took off the plastic shroud that is almost impossible to get off, and it turns out, there is no ignition solenoid or distributor. It's all straight magneto. I cleaned the carb but it already looked pretty good. Will reassemble today.

Comment: When you say "*cannot get it the engine to turnover*", do you mean to say the engine does not crank, or it won't fire? I'm assuming the latter, but don't like to make assumptions.

Comment: Sorry, it's the latter. The engine doesn't fire at all. Wasn't sure how to describe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the carburetor just needed to be rebuilt. Once I was able to do that, the tractor took a second to start up, but it ran great afterwards.